# Old version of job keeps ressurecting after deletion on SideKiq

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq

I have one job that keeps running here is the result from `Sidekiq::Cron::Job.all.to_yaml` my problem is this code hasn't been used in months and i can't delete it for the life of me

I use the SideKiq web ui gem to delete all dead and retry versions of this and have tried using kill as well but nothing is working

```
  - !ruby/object:Sidekiq::Cron::Job
    fetch_missing_args: false
    name: bundle_resolve_job
    cron: 7,27,47 * * * *
    description: ''
    klass: Jobs::Order::Bundle::ResolvePayingJob
    status: enabled
    last_enqueue_time: 2022-07-26 09:27:42.000000000 Z
    args: []
    active_job: false
    active_job_queue_name_prefix: ''
    active_job_queue_name_delimiter: ''
    message: '{"retry":true,"queue":"general","class":"Jobs::Order::Bundle::ResolvePayingJob","args":[]}'
    queue: general
    queue_name_with_prefix: general
```

and this is `config/schedule.yml`

```
global_parcel_resolve_job:
  class: "Jobs::Global::Parcel::ResolvePayingJob"
  cron: "7,27,47 * * * *"
  queue: general
```

how can I permanently remove this job? that keeps using the old version of the code

Answer (score 0):

Create an empty version of the job class. Let it "succeed".